# How to switch the orientation of the Card when printing?

Tags: c#, zebra-printers

I am using the [Zebra Technologies - Card ID Printing – Zebra Card SDK for ZXP Series 3 Printers – C#  sample code](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SA264&actp=LIST). I am having trouble setting the **Orientation** of the card being printed to **Portrait**. I set the orientation to be portrait in the **Printer Preferences** for the printer and clicked **Print Test Page** and a test card came out correctly in portrait orientation. However, when I print a card from the sample application code from the link above it only prints the card in **Landscape** orientation. I even dived into the code, there is nothing that even *uses* or *sets* the orientation of the card anywhere. The only thing I see is in the `ZBRUtil.cs` it has a `enum` called `Orientation` that is never even set or used throughout the entire solution.

[image]

Any advice? I am thinking maybe I need to actually take a look in the `ZBRGraphics.dll` / `ZBRPrinter.dll` 's next (if it will even let me open them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > **You *can't***.

Via - Zebra Support Staff

Comment: from your super post re centering, you also have the option to use "angle" to change the orientation...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48157901/how-can-i-center-text-for-a-label-being-printed-on-a-zebra-zxp-series-3-card

Comment: @smoore4 there ya go, yup.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (but I'm not using the zebra-class printer - I do printing from e.g. Crystal Reports). The clue is : define papersize & it will work.

```
            cryRpt.PrintOptions.PaperSource = PaperSource.Auto;
            cryRpt.PrintOptions.PaperSize = PaperSize.DefaultPaperSize;
            cryRpt.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = PaperOrientation.Landscape;
```

Comment: The answer wouldn't apply to the question if you aren't using the Zebra SDK lol.

Comment: Hi, it's true - I guessed that somewhere the same layer was used (with the same bugs or lack of functionalities)

Comment: We ended up upgrading to the Zebra ZXP Series 7. The SDK architecture is still horrid, but at least it's better than the outdated ZXP3 sdk. I think they are doing a disservice to the word SDK by calling their code a SDK. More like some random lines of code whipped up quickly with no testing

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this that is not so apparent.

First, you set **Printer Preferences** to Portrait as the OP did.  Then, you need to set the same setting in ***"Printing Defaults..."*** It will be different than the one you just set.

The test card is using the Printer Preferences, but the code-based printing is using Defaults.

Printing Defaults is here:

[image]